# How to apply moving average with multiple identical dates

Tags: r, moving-average

I have dataset with a (unique) ID, a date (yyyy-mm-dd format) and an arbitrary measuring value x.

The dataset is sorted by date (first) and, multiple IDs have the same date, by ID (second).

If I plot the data in a scatterplot everything is fine, until I intruduce a moving average for my data.

As some dates can appear multiple times with different measuring values, if I add the moving average to the plot, I have some vertical lines for these days (as there are multiple measuring values as well as multiple moving averages for these days).

Would it be acceptable to have a per day average on which I calculate the moving average or are these vertical lines better in any way or is there yet another way I haven't considered yet to implement the moving average even better?

The dataset and plots are executed with R/Studio.

If necessary I can add some code snippets that help to visualize my problem.

Edit:
The measuring data are the value of the power output measured in Watts) of a given ID (which is unique as mentioned above and is therefore not repeating).
The moving average is needed to help visualizing the change in the power output from day to day.

Edit 2:

example data:

```
ID    Date         Power
1     2023-01-01   10
2     2023-01-01   20
3     2023-01-02   5
4     2023-01-03   15
5     2023-01-05   25
6     2023-01-06   5
7     2023-01-06   30
8     2023-01-06   10
```

"ID" is a unique Identifier, "date" is the date the system goes live and and "power" is the net power usage reported by the system with the respective ID.

For this I want to have an moving average to have a visual hint/overlay in my scatterplot (where each system is marked with date and power) with the mean power up to the last system as the moving average.

If I add a column for the moving average the following happens:

```
ID    Date         Power    mov-avg
1     2023-01-01   10       10
2     2023-01-01   20       15
3     2023-01-02   5        11.7
4     2023-01-03   15       12.5
5     2023-01-05   25       15
6     2023-01-06   5        13.3
7     2023-01-06   30       15.7     
8     2023-01-06   10       15
```

In this case I have two values for the moving average for the date 2023-01-01 (10 and 15) and 3 for the date 2023-01-06 (13.3, 15.7 and 15), which would be displayed as vertical lines if I plot these values on top of my scatterplot.

Comment: It depends on what this "measuring value" represents and what your moving average is intended to represent.  Please let us know in your future edits.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not terribly informative.  Could you tell us what an "ID" represents and how it is related to the daily "power output"?  And, again, please tell us what your objective is in computing this moving window.  In some applications it's perfectly correct for the moving average to jump and in others it's not, *even with the same data.*

Comment: ok, thanks for the information, I will give an excerpt and explanation from the data later when I am back.

Comment: @whuber I added the example data I hope this helps clarifying my problem/issue.

Comment: The moving average gives you a sense of the change in power output *per ID.* That's why it can jump within the course of a day.  That does not look like a problem, but if you think it is, it suggests you are really trying to solve a different problem related to the temporal changes in power outputs.  Thus, your question might have a clear answer once you can settle on what it is you really need to do. For instance, to visualize how per-ID outputs vary over time, why not plot them individually? Various smoothers will do a good job of showing you local trends, flexibly.